# how to give different background color to options in select tag during hover

Tags: css

```
<select name=""   id="gender"  name ="gender" class="genderClass">
<option value="0">Please select gender</option>
<option value="1">Male</option>
<option value="2">Female</option>
</select>
```

This is the class:

```
.genderClass:hover
{
    background: gray;
}
```

Currently `mouseover` to the `select` tag gives me gray color. But when opening the tag and options came how can I set `background-color` to options, while I `mouseover` on it. ie. if i move mouse over to female `option` then `background-color` should be changed to gray color. 
How can I do that?

[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/reshmasalim/K2hdP/)

Comment: Can you put it in Fiddle

Comment: `.genderClass:hover option {...}`?

Comment: Repeat....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895476/how-to-style-a-select-dropdown-with-css-only-without-javascript

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/reshmasalim/K2hdP/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can't do it only using `css` but using `javascript` you can achieve it using a custom select. If you use `jQuery` then below is two plugin's example you may like.

1. [Sparkbox Custom-Selectbox](https://github.com/sparkbox/Custom-Selectbox) and [an example here](http://jsfiddle.net/yDzgu/).
2. [jQuery custom selectboxes](http://info.wsisiz.edu.pl/~suszynsk/jQuery/demos/jquery-selectbox/) and [an example here.](http://jsfiddle.net/TP98Q/1/)

Also you can find more if you search on Google [like this one](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+custom+select&oq=javascript+custom+select&aqs=chrome.0.57j62l3.13384&sugexp=chrome,mod=5&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: other than jquery-1.8.2.min.js what al files should i include to work this in an html page. **Object [object Object] has no method 'selectbox'** error for line `$(function(){$(".sparkbox-custom").selectbox();`     when i am trying this in an html page

Comment: i like the page [google link](http://lab.aspektas.com/select/select.html) in which they replace select with ul li tags. thank u for suggesting the google link

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of specifying the selected option in order to change its background-color. Applying a background to either the select or option tags will change the background either on the entire select except for the selected entry or for all the options except for the selected entry.

The only way I believe it is possible to change the color of the background on the selected entry is via the theme you define within your operating system on your computer and that will only change it for you and not for your visitors.